# How to convert a multi-row result set into a single-row text separated by commas

Tags: sql-server, string, parse

I'm using this query

```
select Name, valueType from mytable where ID = 1
```

and getting this table:

[image]

But I need to covert the result set into something like:

```
'idGasto int, noTicket string, fechaFact string, ..., etc.'
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
--demo setup
Declare @Table table (Name varchar(100), ValueType varchar(100))
DECLARE @ConcatString varchar(100)

insert into @Table values
('idGasto','int'), 
('noTicket','String'), 
('fechaFact','String'), 
('fecha','String'), 
('concepto','String')

--The actual query
SELECT @ConcatString = isnull(@ConcatString + ',', '') + Name + ' ' + ValueType
from @Table

print @ConcatString
```

---

```
idGasto int,noTicket String,fechaFact String,fecha String,concepto String
```

**NOTE:  If you are on at least SQL Server 2017, you can use `STRING_AGG`:**

```
Declare @Table table (Name varchar(100), ValueType varchar(100))
DECLARE @ConcatString varchar(100)

insert into @Table values
('idGasto','int'), 
('noTicket','String'), 
('fechaFact','String'), 
('fecha','String'), 
('concepto','String')

--If you're on at least SQL Server 2017, you can use STRING_AGG
select @ConcatString = STRING_AGG(Name + ' ' + ValueType, ',') 
from @table

print @ConcatString
```

---

```
idGasto int,noTicket String,fechaFact String,fecha String,concepto String
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use COALESCE

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL + ', ', '') + Col1 + '.' + Col2 
FROM table

PRINT @SQL
```